# Prove if a = b, then f(a) = f(b) for any function f (with natural deduction)

Tags: functions, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

I want to be able to prove that for all functions f, that $a = b \to f(a) = f(b)$.  That this is true is obvious, but I'm not sure how to formally prove it using only the rules of inference in first-order logic (using natural deduction).  I'm guessing I need to reference a formal definition for a function, where $f \subset A \times B$ and satisfies:

$$ (\forall x \in A)(\exists y \in B)((x,y) \in f \wedge (\forall z \in B)((x,z) \in f\to y=z))$$

However, I don't have any clue where to begin with this.  Can anyone help?  Please only give hints/answers using natural deduction as the deductive system.

Comment: If you are using logic alone (like *Natural Deduction*) you have no definition of a function $f \subset A \times B$. What you can have are *function symbols* $f_i^k$. In this case : $a = b \to f(a) = f(b)$ is a rule of FOL with equality (sometimes called : $=$-elimination).

Comment: If instead you are working in set theory, your def is the usual def of *function*. Thus, from $(a,c_1) \in f$ and $(b, c_2)$ and $a=b$ it follows $(a,c_1), (a,c_2) \in f$. Thus, by def of function, $c_1=c_2$ and $f(a)=c_1=c_2=f(b)$.

Comment: In set theory the question doesn't even make sense because the notation only carries meaning if $f$ is a function and if it is, there's nothing to prove other than the lone step Mauro specified above.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - sorry I should have stated that I am working within set theory.  I know that this might sound pathological but I want to understand the mechanics of the proof using the inference rules.  For example, in your explanation above, you can infer from the formulas $(b, c_2) \in f$ and $a = b$ that $(a, c_2) \in f$ by using the =-elimination rule.  But how do I prove $c_1 = c_2$ from the definition of the function?.  I've made attempts using $\forall$-elimination and $\exists$-elimination to strip the quantifiers from def of function but with no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To prove it in set  theory, we need some definitions and some basic results :

> Definition of *function* : $(∀x)(∀y)(∀z)(\langle x,y \rangle \in f \land \langle x,z \rangle \in f \to y = z)$;

equality between ([Kuratowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski_definition)) *pairs* :

> $\langle x,y \rangle = \langle u,v \rangle  \to x = u \land y = v$;

definition of *domain* of a relation:

> $\mathcal D R$ is the set of all $x$ such that, for some $y : \ \langle x,y \rangle \in R$.

We cannot prove the formula in your question as is, due to the fact that not all functions are *total*.

We have to rewrite it as :

> if $a \in \mathcal D f$ and $a=b$, then $f(a)=f(b)$.

We need also to formalize the abbreviation $f(x)$; form the definition of function we have:

> for every $a \in \mathcal D f : \ \exists ! y  \ (\langle a,y \rangle \in f)$.

Thus, we are licensed to write :

> for every $a \in \mathcal D f : f(a)=\iota y \ (\langle a,y \rangle \in f)$.

---

Now for the proof :

1) $a \in \mathcal D f$ --- assumed [a]

2) $a=b$ --- assumed [b]

3) $\langle a, f(a) \rangle \in f$ --- from 1) and *abbreviation*

4) $\langle b, f(b) \rangle \in f$ --- from 2) and 3)

5) $\langle a, f(b) \rangle \in f$ --- from 2) and 4).

*Note* : the above steps are substitutions of *terms* into formulae. The formula is : $\{ a, \{a, f(a) \} \} \in f$ and we use the *equality axiom* :

> $a = b \to (\varphi \to \varphi')$, where where $\varphi'$ is obtained from $\varphi$ by replacing $a$ in zero or more (but not necessarily all) places by $b$.

Form the definition of function, by *instantiation* (or : $\forall$-elim) :

6) $\langle a,f(a) \rangle \in f \land \langle a,f(b) \rangle \in f \to f(a) = f(b)$.

7) $f(a) = f(b)$ --- from 6), 3) and 5) by *modus ponens* twice.

Thus, discharging assumptions [a] and [b] by *Deduction Th* (or : $\to$-intro) :

> > $a \in \mathcal D f \land a=b \to f(a) = f(b)$.

The conclusion (for every $a$ ...) follows by *generalization* (or : $\forall$-intro).

Comment: Thanks for the proof, but thee are a couple of aspects I don't follow.  The definition of the function at the start seems to allow elements in $f $  that make it not a function.  For example, assume the domain is natural numbers, then (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), etc seem to satisfy the formula.  Am I missing something?  Also I'm unfamiliar with the $\iota $ notation.   What does this mean?

Comment: @esotechnica - No, it cannot; if $(1,1) \in F$ and $(1,2) \in f$ then (by the definition) : $1=2$.

Comment: Sorry it is taking me a while to digest this.  I understand now where the fault in my reasoning was.

Comment: can't one jump directly from 3) to 5)? what's the point of the 4) step?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since you asked your question, but I suppose the answer you're looking for is this one. Basically, you want to prove that $F : X \rightarrow Y$ implies $\forall x' \in X \forall x'' \in X [x'=x'' \rightarrow F(x') = F(x'')]$. As you correctly stated, $F : X \rightarrow Y$ can be translated in predicate logic as $\forall x[x \in X \rightarrow \exists y[y \in Y \land (x,y) \in F \land \forall z[z \in Y \land (x, z) \in F \rightarrow y=z]]]$. As a sidenote, the expression $\forall x' \in X \forall x'' \in X [x'=x'' \rightarrow F(x') = F(x'')]$ is equivalent to $\forall x'  \forall x'' [(x' \in X \land x'' \in X \land x'=x'') \rightarrow F(x') = F(x'')]$.

The first step in our proof is to declare $x'$ and $x''$ as arbitrary variables. As a consequence, the goal of our proof turns into $(x' \in X \land x'' \in X \land x'=x'') \rightarrow F(x') = F(x'')$. The second step is to hypothetically assume $x' \in X$, $x'' \in X$ and $x'=x''$. As a consequence, the goal turns into $F(x') = F(x'')$. Hence:

PREMISE 1: $\forall x[x \in X \rightarrow \exists y[y \in Y \land (x,y) \in F \land \forall z[z \in Y \land (x, z) \in F \rightarrow y=z]]]$

PREMISE 2: $x' \in X$

PREMISE 3: $x'' \in X$

PREMISE 4: $x'=x''$

GOAL: $F(x') = F(x'')$

We apply universal instantiation upon PREMISE 1 to derive $x' \in X \rightarrow \exists y[y \in Y \land (x',y) \in F \land \forall z[z \in Y \land (x', z) \in F \rightarrow y=z]]$ and $x'' \in X \rightarrow \exists y[y \in Y \land (x'',y) \in F \land \forall z[z \in Y \land (x'', z) \in F \rightarrow y=z]]$. Since we have $x' \in X$ (PREMISE 2) and $x'' \in X$ (PREMISE 3), we use modus ponens and conclude $\exists y[y \in Y \land (x',y) \in F \land \forall z[z \in Y \land (x', z) \in F \rightarrow y=z]]$ and $\exists y[y \in Y \land (x'',y) \in F \land \forall z[z \in Y \land (x'', z) \in F \rightarrow y=z]]$.

Now, we should use existential instantiation to get rid of the existential quantifiers in both statements. Therefore, we introduce the variables $y'$ and $y''$ and assume the premises $y' \in Y \land (x',y') \in F \land \forall z[z \in Y \land (x', z) \in F \rightarrow y'=z]$ and $y'' \in Y \land (x'',y'') \in F \land \forall z[z \in Y \land (x'', z) \in F \rightarrow y''=z]$. Notice that the first expression means the same as $y' = F(x')$ and the second expression means $y'' = F(x'').$

At this point, we use universal instantiation at the uniqueness part of both expressions, substituting $z$ in the first expression by $y''$ and $z$ in the second expression by $y'$. Hence, $y' \in Y \land (x',y') \in F \land [y'' \in Y \land (x', y'') \in F \rightarrow y'=y'']$ and $y'' \in Y \land (x'',y'') \in F \land [y' \in Y \land (x'', y') \in F \rightarrow y''=y']$.

Since we have $y' \in Y \land (x',y') \in F$ and since $x'=x''$ (PREMISE 4), then, by modus ponens, we conclude $y' \in Y \land (x'',y') \in F$. Since we have from the uniqueness part of the second statement that $[y' \in Y \land (x'', y') \in F \rightarrow y''=y']$, then we conclude by modus pones $y''=y'$. Since $y'=F(x')$, since $y''=F(x'')$ and since $y'=y''$, we conclude $F(x')=F(x'')$. The same reasoning could have been applied upon statement 2 and the uniqueness part in statement 1 to reach the same result.