# Natural deduction proof of $a = b \rightarrow f(a) = f(b)$. Where have I gone wrong?

Tags: functions, proof-verification, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

I am trying to prove a basic property of functions using the steps of natural deduction, within set theory.  Namely, that if a = b, then f(a) = f(b) for any function f.  I know the proof I have come up with is faulty (I will explain below why), but I'm not sure at which line this occurs.

First, I assert the following definitions:

[Def 1] $ \forall x(x \in D(f) \to \exists y((x,y) \in f \wedge \forall z((x,z)\in f \to y = z)))$ -- Defines a function $f$ with domain $D(f)$

[Def 2] $ \forall x \forall y(f(x) = y \leftrightarrow (x,y) \in f)$  -- Defines the notation $f(x)$

and from this I want to prove:

$$ \forall x \forall y((x \in D(f) \wedge x = y) \to f(x) = f(y))$$

Here is the proof I use:

1. $a \in D(f)~~~~~~~~~\text{(Assumption)}$
2. $ a = b~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{(Assumption)}$
3. $ a \in D(f) \to \exists y((a,y) \in f \wedge \forall z((a,z)\in f \to y = z))~~~~~~~(\forall \text{-elim, Def 1.})$
4. $ \exists y((a,y) \in f \wedge \forall z((a,z)\in f \to y = z))~~~(\to\text{elim; 1, 3})$
5. $ (a,c) \in f \wedge \forall z((a,z)\in f \to c = z)~~~~\text{(Assumption)}$
6. $ (a,c) \in f~~~~~~(\wedge\text{-elim, 5.})$
7. $ f(a) = c \leftrightarrow (a,c) \in f~~~~(\forall\text{-elim twice on Def 2.})$
8. $ (a,c) \in f \to f(a) = c ~~~~~~~(\leftrightarrow\text{elim; 7.})$
9. $ f(a) = c~~~~~(\to\text{elim; 6, 8})$
10. $ (a, f(a)) \in f~~~~~~\text{(=-elim; 6, 9.  Also, assumption at 5. is discharged by }\exists\text{-elim.)}$
11. $ (b, f(a)) \in f~~~~~~\text{(=-elim; 2, 10)}$
12. $ f(b) = f(a) \leftrightarrow (b,f(a)) \in f~~~~(\forall\text{-elim twice on Def 2.})$
13. $ (b,f(a)) \in f \to f(b) = f(a) ~~~~~~~(\leftrightarrow\text{elim; 12.})$
14. $ f(b) = f(a)~~~~~(\to\text{elim; 11,13})$
15. $ f(a) = f(b)~~~~~\text{(=-symm; 14)}$
16. $ (a \in D(f) \wedge a = b) \to f(a) = f(b)~~~~~~\text{(Discharge assumptions 1 and 2)}$
17. $ \forall x \forall y((x \in D(f) \wedge x = y) \to f(x) = f(y))~~~~~~~~~(\forall\text{-intro used twice)}$

(Note: I use the natural deduction rules of inference defined in Chiswell & Hodges: Mathematical Logic)

This proof must be wrong, because it doesn't use the key part of Def. 1 at all, which ensures the uniqueness of a function's value for some input. That is, I can just $\wedge$-elim it away at step 6!  Can anyone point out at which step I have made an error?

PS. Sorry about the poor formatting of the proof lines, but I don't have enough latex knowledge to format it neatly.

Comment: Can you use the axiom of replacement?

Comment: The 'problem' is that you use a function-symbol, which first-order logic immediately treats as being functional, i.e. as having the property that you try to prove. Indeed, in my Answer below, I show that using the function symbol, the proof is trivial. So if you want to treat a function as a non-logical object, you just need to not use function-symbols (at least not for f itself).  Essentially, you need to get rid of Def. 2, and just use Def. 1 to get your desired result ... though that result will look very much like Def. 1 itself! See my Answer below for what that might look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first-order logic, function symbols are inherently treated to be things that work functionally, and so from $a=b$, it will *logically* follow that $f(a) = f(b)$:

1. $a=b \qquad\quad\qquad$ Assumption
2. $f(a)=f(a) \qquad$ = Intro
3. $f(a)=f(b) \qquad$ = Elim 1,2

Now, I know you tried to avoid doing this by creating an axiomatic definition for a function, and trying to derive its functionality from that. However, you ended up using functional symbols, and in fact on line 10 you exploited the inherent functionality of the function symbols in logic after all, thus effectively doing what the proof above does after all, and thus eliminating the need for Def. 1.

To avoid such unintended exploitations of the nature of functional symbols in logic, I would recommend to 1) avoid function symbols altogether, 2) use Def. 1 as your one and only axiomatic definition of a function, 3) get rid of Def. 2, and 4) rephrase your goal to not use function symbols either, and instead use something like:

$ \forall x \forall y ((x \in D(f) \wedge y \in D(f) \wedge x = y) \to \forall v \forall w (((x,v) \in f \wedge (y,w) \in f) \to v = w))$

Below is a Natural Deduction proof for the desired result when following that approach.

[image]

Comment: This is something I don't quite understand.  I know that proving in FOL only requires this basic proof, but from what I have learnt from other posts when working in set theory it requires more work than this, as we are working with functions as an entity with special semantics, and not just syntactic elements.

Comment: @esotechnica Well, another option is indeed to define a function with an axiom, as you tried to do. But in that case, I would stick to predicate symbol, and avoid functional symbols completely. Let me amend my answer to give you some direction.

Comment: Thanks, i think I'm understanding this clearer now.  Let me just check my understanding.  So, both proofs are just as valid as each other.  The simple proof in FOL is simple because the nature of functionality is "built in" to FOL.  That is, it is already understand what the meaning is behind function symbols, so there is little to show.  The more elaborate proof, because it avoids function symbols, must explicitly define what a function is using an axiom, and prove other properties of the function without using any function symbols.

Comment: By the way, what is the software you are using for the proof generation?  Is it freely available?

Comment: And does anyone know why @ tags aren't working?  I've tried to put "@Bram28" at the start of each comment and it just deletes them...

Comment: @esotechnica yes, your summary of the situation is correct.  The software I use is called Firch and comes with the book Language Proof and Logic ... Which is not free.  And no, I don't know why the tags aren't working :p

Comment: Just one more question.  Is there any point to creating a proof of the behaviour of functions in set theory?  Because it can already be proven in FOL (the semantics are understood).  That is, why do set theory text books create definitions of functions?  I assume this is to show that our "intuitive" idea of what a function is in FOL can be modelled by certain types of sets (relations), thereby giving some formal notion of a set that transcends our implicit understanding of it in FOL, because FOL is really just manipulation of meaningless symbols.

Comment: @esotechnica Right, while function symbols in FOL are treated in a way that reflects certain properties of functions (in particular, that a function maps one object to exactly one other object), there are other things true about functions that are not built into FOL, e.g. that they have an inverse when left-unique. And sometimes we want to talk about partial functions, while the functions built into FOL are assumed to be total.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the *relation* "$\text {Son_of}(x,y)$" and introduce the notation $\text {Son_of}(x)=y$.

We have that :

> if $ \ \text {John} = \text {Bobby} \ $, then $ \ \text {Son_of}(\text {John}) = \text {Son_of}(\text {Bobby}).$

But from :

> $ \ \text {Son_of}(\text {John}) = \text {Ron} \ $ and $ \ \text {Son_of}(\text {John}) = \text {Tommy}$

does not follow that :

> $ \ \text {Ron} = \text {Tommy} \ $.

What has gone wrong ? The definition of the notation $\text {Son_of}(x)=y$.

We cannot use it with the relation "$\text {Son_of}(x,y)$" because it is not *functional*.

Thus, in your proof, to apply [Def 2] you have implicitly assumed that also the uniqueness clause of [Def 1] holds.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, do you mean that I should make Def 2. conditional on Def 1?  That is, if I were to combine both formulas as one formula of the form (Def 1 -> Def 2), and use this in my proof, would this be the way to go?

Comment: @esotechnica - I've have already proved it in your previous [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1965196/prove-if-a-b-then-fa-fb-for-any-function-f-with-natural-deduction) : [Def.2] is allowed only because from [Def.1] we can prove : "for every $a ∈ D(f): ∃!y (⟨a,y⟩ ∈ f) $".